# Iterative implementation of Binary Search

Tags: c, algorithm

please i have a question about the Iterative implementation of Binary Search

This is the function i create in c:

```
int BinarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x)
{
  while(l <=  r) {
      int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
      if(arr[mid] == x)
          return mid;
      if(arr[mid] > x)
          r = mid - 1;
      else
          l = mid + 1;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

This is my main function :

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,5,16,15,20};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int x = 16;
    int result = BinarySearch(arr, 0, n-1, x);
    (result == -1)
        // WE CALL THIS ternary operator.
        ? printf("Element is not present in array")
        : printf("Element is present at index %d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

The question is: when i search 16 the function return -1.
If you see the number 16 is on the list any help please ??

Comment: Please do not abuse tags.

Comment: binary search requires a sorted array, `arr` is not sorted

Comment: Also `java` and `javascript` should be excluded from the list of tag for this question

Comment: ah, sorry about that but the question is not a question for c juste the algorithme is writing the question was general for all programming langages ?

Comment: @UnholySheep you are awesome thanks bro  hhhh i'a'm laughing about this Thanks for replay

Comment: Yes, it is generic, for this you should not add the tags, as it's not specific for the languages. You are using C language in this question, you can add the C tag. If somebody has java/python/javascript knowledge maybe is not able to read your C code.

Comment: Okey @Raffaele i'am new here i want juste some help java or python dosent matter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the **ARRAY MUST BE SORTED** thanks to @UnholySheep